# How to make panel draggable in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, panel

I give my users the ability to create items. The Create item dialogs such as:

```
    <s:Panel id="postitNoteCreatePanel" 
             horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0"
             ...
```

How can I make panel draggable so that users can move it around the page so it doesn't block other items

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may try:

Add mouse down and mouse up eventlistner to the titleBar of the panel, and add two functions:

```
    private function handleDown(event:MouseEvent):void{
        this.startDrag();
    }

    private function handleUp(event:MouseEvent):void{
        this.stopDrag();
    }
```

"this" is refer the the panel.

Comment: If there is clickable items as children on the panel, would you use stop immediate propogation to stop the panel being moved accidently i.e. only the title part would trigger a move?

Comment: Only the title part will be draggable, the panel itself will not have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an event listener to the panel, i.e on mousedown, you can make the startDrag property of the panel true, and on mouseup (after mousedown) , you can stop dragging the panel.

This is the easiest way to do this.Though this would mean the user will be able to drag the panel using any part of the panel.

Comment: do something like <s:panel mouseDown="{this.startDrag()}" mouseUp="{this.stopDrag()}..... /> But as specified, this would allow the user to move panel, by clikcing on any part of the panel.Also, if you are comfortable with using other libraries, check FlexLib, it takes care of such cases very elegantly.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this in my opinion is to substitute your s:Panel with a s:TitleWindow.  The TitleWindow skin adds an area to the titlebar allowing it to be dragged and the TitleWindow class has code to deal with dragging.  This will allow dragging without you having to code any handlers.  Hope that helps.

Comment: One difference is the TitleWindow resides always on the top layer of the application, so it remains present when you switch states (or views). However, a draggable Panel can remain in one state (or view), and is still there when you return to that state.

Answer (score 1):

Here is example and code for draggable (and resizable) flex Panels, older SDK though!!

http://blogs.adobe.com/flexdoc/2007/03/creating_resizable_and_draggab.html

[image]

Answer (score 0):

code blew can help you. I use this code in flex 4.5. It works perfectly.

http://code.google.com/p/force-explorer/source/browse/trunk/Flex/Explorer/src/components/DraggablePanel.as?r=8

```
package components
{
        import flash.events.MouseEvent;

        import mx.managers.DragManager;

        import spark.components.Group;
        import spark.components.Panel;

        /**
         * A simple extension of the Spark Panel component
         * that enables dragging.
         */
        public class DraggablePanel extends Panel
        {
                //--------------------------------------
                // Constructor
                //--------------------------------------

                public function DraggablePanel()
                {
                        super();
                }

                //--------------------------------------
                // Skin Parts
                //--------------------------------------

                /**
                 * The skin part that represents the title bar of the underlying Panel.
                 *      NOTE: The default PanelSkin already has this, it's just not defined as a skinPart in the Panel class.
                 * We want it so that we can capture dragging.
                 */
                [SkinPart(required="true")]
                public var topGroup:Group;

                //--------------------------------------
                // Overridden Methods
                //--------------------------------------

                protected override function partAdded( partName:String, instance:Object ) : void
                {
                        super.partAdded( partName, instance );

                        if (instance == topGroup)
                        {
                                Group( instance ).addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, topGroup_mouseDownHandler );
                                Group( instance ).addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, topGroup_mouseUpHandler );
                        }
                }

                protected override function partRemoved( partName:String, instance:Object ) : void
                {
                        super.partRemoved( partName, instance );

                        if (instance == topGroup)
                        {
                                Group( instance ).removeEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, topGroup_mouseDownHandler );
                                Group( instance ).removeEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, topGroup_mouseUpHandler );
                        }
                }

                //--------------------------------------
                // Event Handlers
                //--------------------------------------

                protected function topGroup_mouseDownHandler( event:MouseEvent ):void
                {
                        if ( !DragManager.isDragging )
                                startDrag();
                }

                protected function topGroup_mouseUpHandler( event:MouseEvent ):void
                {
                        stopDrag();
                }
        }
}
```

---

http://code.google.com/p/force-explorer/source/browse/trunk/Flex/Explorer/src/components/DraggablePanel.as?r=8